# Git bash completion does not complete git commands as expected

Tags: bash, git, completion

After setting up bash completion support for `git` (version 2.14.5
 on Slackware Linux 14.2) using the file `contrib/completion/git-completion.bash` from the *git* master repository as described and already did for other commands, I expected to get **git commands** as completion words on ususal *TAB-completion* hits like for `git [TAB][TAB]`. For instance:

```
$ git c[TAB][TAB]
checkout commit clone ...
```

Instead of getting any **git commands** like `checkout`, `commit`, or else, only filenames are suggested or completed. Whereas, when requesting completion with dashes like `git --b[TAB][TAB]`, then **git options**, like `--bare` are suggested or completed well.

I know, there are a lot of similar questions out there, but despite searching the answers, I could not find a proper solution to solve this issue.

- The `git-completion.bash` file is sourced correctly; after sourcing with `. git-completion.bash` its functions are available in the executing bash environment, as `declare -f` shows.
- The `progcomp` shell option is `on`.
- The *git* completion function is registered as the output of `complete -p git` shows:

  ```
  $ complete -p git
  complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git
  ```
- After inspecting the sourced `git-completion.bash` file, I can say, the completion function `__git_wrap__git_main` is called on `git [TAB]` hits, but the `COMPREPLY` variable is not filled with completion words when requesting completion without *double-dashes* `--*`

Has anybody an idea why only **git options** are completed while **git commands** are not?

Comment: What gt version are you using? On which OS?

Comment: Updated question details: GIT version 2.14.5 on Slackware Linux 14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Git 2.14, there have been many improvement to completion ([Git 2.18](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671467/6309) notably), I would first check if the same issue persists with Git 2.26 (possibly [using slpkg](https://dslackw.gitlab.io/slpkg/))

The [`contrib/completion/git-completion.bash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) has a rich and recent [history](https://github.com/git/git/commits/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash).

Comment: Basically I am not a friend of reinstalling parts of a working environment. So changing the entire git suite to get in return a simple bash completion working seems quite expensive especially when considering the fact, that the running environment - which heavily uses a lot of the existing git features - is working well.

Comment: The completion script is a bash script that makes use of the *Bash Completion Facility*. I thought that it could not be a big deal for a completion script to supply *static* completion words; just the **most basic** git commands which `git help` shows. *Far failed. A good example how easy it s to fall into error.*

**However, I followed your advice, and compiled git based on its current sources
what lead to correct completion functionality.**
Although it is not clear why the completion script was not working with version 2.14, there is left to say: Thank you.

Comment: @Nero You are welcome. That seems indeed a bit extreme as a solution, but I cannot rule out interaction between the up-to-date completion script and an up-to-date Git, which would make said script work correctly (when used with the latest Git release)